# Cannot register a block in my Twig-based theme using Timber for WP

Tags: plugins, templates

I'm trying to configure my custom block theme with Twig templates using the plugin Timber 1.22 on WordPress 6

First, I disabled WP built-in rendering of `templates/index.html` in `functions.php` (otherwise both WP built-in and Twig renderings are executed) by adding a redirection to my `timber-twig.php` file as below

```
function my_template_include($template) {
    if(strpos($template, 'template-canvas.php') !== false) {
        $template = get_stylesheet_directory().'/timber-twig.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'my_template_include');
```

Next, in my `timber-twig.php` I placed the code

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/timber-library/vendor/autoload.php');

Timber::$dirname = ['templates'];
$context = Timber::context();
$context['post'] = Timber::get_post();
Timber::render('my-block.html', $context);
```

And `my-block.html` looks like

```
{% extends "index.html" %}{# I use the same index.html instead of base.twig #}
{% block content %}
{{ post.content }}
{% endblock %}
```

It's working fine and Twig template is rendered

But now I would like to register my block to make it editable in the WordPress editor

In `functions.php` I add the following piece of code

```
add_action('init', function() {
    register_block_type('my-block', [
        'render_callback' => function($attributes, $content) {
            Timber::$dirname = ['templates'];
            $context = Timber::context();
            $context['attributes'] = $attributes;
            $context['content'] = $content;
            Timber::render('my-block.html', $context);
        },
    ]);
});
```

But in the admin editor I still get the error

> This block has encountered an error and cannot be previewed.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: that's a generic error, the real/actual error message is in your browsers dev console, but don't expect to be able to type to edit that block

Comment: Here is what I see in console `TypeError: window.wpEditorL10n is undefined http://localhost/wp-includes/js/dist/block-library.min.js?ver=eaf9a7d8b936d26afead09af3f82b117:14 http://localhost/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9`